# Joining on 3 different keys as they're set

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have these tables:

```
TABLE vessels
ID int PK
organization_id int FK
fleet_id int FK
name VARCHAR

TABLE settings
ID int PK
organization_id int NULL FK
fleet_id int NULL FK
vessel_id int NULL FK
some_value INT
```

In table settings, `some_value` can be either 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 or 7

Some entries in the `settings` table are linked to a `vessel_id` based on it's `fleet_id` or `organization_id`

How do I go about selecting the settings for a `vessel`, if a vessel has settings via it's `fleet_id` or `organization_id` ?

Comment: What? Sample data and desired result would make this question much clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When tables are related using specific columns, you can use various types of JOINs to connect the tables and get data. The [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) has a page on JOIN syntax. [Here](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/) is a website with some examples.

The following query uses an INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT
    v.ID
    ,v.organization_id
    ,v.fleet_id
    ,v.name
    ,s.some_value
FROM vessels v
INNER JOIN settings s
ON v.fleet_id = s.fleet_id OR v.organization_id = s.organization_id
ORDER BY v.name;
```

I do note that the settings table has vessel_id, which seems like a FK to the vessels table. If you wish to use this column, then simply change the ON condition to `ON v.ID = s.vessel_id`.

Comment: How would I extend this query to not give double records if `organization_id`, `fleet_id` AND `vessel_id` have records in `settings` ?

Comment: You could perhaps use DISTINCT or tighten up the JOIN condition. Could you please post the data that you have and the expected output?